# Android - Frequency isn't correct after compute FFT

Tags: java, android, audio, fft, audiorecord

I start record a sound from AudioRecord with some parameters.

```
private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 44100;
private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;
private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
this.recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
            RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, this.bufferSize);
```

I store the data into an ArrayList< byte[] > soundRecord;

```
while (this.isRecording) {
    read = this.recorder.read(data, 0, this.bufferSize);
    if (AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != read) {
        try {
            soundRecord.add(data);
            os.write(data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my method for compute my sound into a complex array FFT. Before doing it, I convert byte into double.

```
public ArrayList<double[]> computeFFT(byte[] audioSignal) {
    final int fftPoint = 65536;
    ArrayList<double[]> result;

    double tmp;
    Complex[] y;
    Complex[] complexAudioSignal = new Complex[fftPoint];
    double[] magnitude = new double[fftPoint / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < fftPoint; i++) {
        if (i >= 22050) tmp = 0;
        else tmp = (double) ((audioSignal[2 * i] & 0xFF) | (audioSignal[2 * i + 1] << 8) / 32768.0F;
        complexAudioSignal[i] = new Complex(tmp, 0.0);
    }

    y = FFF.fft(complexAudioSignal);

    // Calculate magnitude values from fft[]
    for (int i = 0; (fftPoint / 2); i++) {
        magnitude[i] = y[i].abs();
    }

    // get only values over mid value
    result = showFrequencies(magnitude, fftPoint);
    return result;
}
```

My problem is, I test a constant sound with 440Hz (A4 from the piano).
I get in my array "magnitude" a peak, but the frequency for this peak is 220Hz.
Everytime I try a sample sound with only one frequency (I use n-track), the frequency is the real frequency / 2.

I know the frequency is f = index * SAMPLE_RATE / fftPoint.

Someone can help me please. I have this problem since 3 days...

---

Edit One :

I modify my conversion loop like you suggest. It's look like that :

```
int bytePerSample =2;
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < audioSignal.length / 2; i++) {
    if (( i % 8 == 0 || i % 8 == 2 ) && i < 22050) {
        tmp = (double) ((audioSignal[bytesPerSample * i] & 0xFF) | audioSignal[bytePerSample * i + 1] << 8)) / 32768.0F;
        complexAudioSignal[j] = new Complex(tmp, 0.0);
        j++;
    }
}
```

The problem right now is FrequencyIWant = FreqIObtain / 2.
I really don't know what to do now :'(.

Comment: You seem to be off by a factor of two: did you neglect to take into account that your recording is stereo with interleaved channels?  Or did you perhaps convert single bytes to samples, instead of pairs of bytes?  Either mistake would, amongst other problems, be somewhat like having a sample rate twice what you think it is.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I am a beginner in Audio, so I don't understand/know what are you talking. Can you put some examples please?

Comment: You will need to take time to understand these subjects if you hope to make any progress on an audio analysis project.  But if you aren't meaning to process stereo channels, change your source setting to mono.

Answer (score 2):

You are copying both stereo channels into your FFT, instead of just the left or right channel.  Try using 2 sequential bytes out of every 4 bytes in your integer unpacking and conversion loop.

Comment: Thanks !! I change my record into AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO. And now, I have the right frequency.

Comment: With CHANNEL_IN_MONO, the sound is in accelerate, and value is absurd. How can I do the thing you suggest ?